# Why I can not use sass variables to define value of css variable

Tags: css, sass, css-variables, dart-sass

I am trying to use sass variables and sass mathematical operator to define different css `font-size` variables.

I defined css variables like that:

```
$base-font-size: 1rem;

:root {
  --font-size-s: #{$base-font-size} * 0.5;
  --font-size-m: #{$base-font-size};
  --font-size-l: #{$base-font-size} * 2;
}
```

Then in other file I used my css variable like that:

```
p {
  font-size: var(--font-size-l);
}
```

This doesn't work at all my font size doesn't change at all. I thought that maybe there is something wrong with sass mathematical operators, so I tried something like that:

```
p {
  font-size: 1rem * 2;
}
```

This worked and my font size was equal `2rem` as expected. After this discovery I thought that maybe I am doing something wrong with sass variables so changed my css variables to that:

```
:root {
  --font-size-s: 1rem * 0.5;
  --font-size-m: 1rem;
  --font-size-l: 1rem * 2;
}
```

And this doesn't work! I really do not know what I am doing wrong. Can someone explain to me how should I define those css variables with sass variables and sass mathematical operators?

**Notes:**

- If I use css `calc` function this will work too:

```
:root {
  --font-size-s: calc(#{$base-font-size} * 0.5);
  --font-size-m: #{$base-font-size};
  --font-size-l: calc(#{$base-font-size} * 2);
}
```

- For compiling `.scss` files I am using ***Webpack 5.10.3*** with **css-loader** and **sass-loader**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to evalute all the expression like below:

```css
$base-font-size: 1rem;

:root {
  --font-size-s: #{$base-font-size * 0.5};
  --font-size-m: #{$base-font-size};
  --font-size-l: #{$base-font-size * 2};
}
```